# Cannot fatch json file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, postman

i think this is to basic question, but this is problem i have right now and i cannot find solution.

I am trying to show data from API i created on postman

React.js code is here

```
  const urlCategories = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories';
  const [service, setService] = useState([]);
  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(urlCategories);
    const service = await response.json();
    console.log(service);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);
```

error in console

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at
> line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Your API isn't responding with a valid JSON string that can be parsed/converted into a  JS object,  check what your API is responding with

Comment: @NickParsons it looks right for me [{"id":1,"parent_id":1,"title":"\u0160tampa","created_at":"2021-04-27T12:39:52.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-27T12:39:52.000000Z"},....

Comment: Check what's happening in the network inspector of your browser. You might be getting an error message due to e.g. not passing credentials (`fetch(..., {credentials: 'same-origin'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http missing

```
const urlCategories = 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories';
  const [service, setService] = useState([]);
  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(urlCategories);
    const service = await response.json();
    console.log(service);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
  }, []);
```